# How can I set a trigger for the animator states to start with a trigger/event?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The fading in and out is working fine. but it's starting fading right when starting the game.
I want it to be start fading in and out but only at some point in the game not when running it.

Should I use a trigger ? Or event ?
I created two triggers FadeOut and FadeIn

[image: Animator settings]

Both states transitions settings are the same.

The problem is that the Set StateMachine Default Set make the fading start automatic when running the game.

A script I used before but not using right now :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FadeInOutSaveGameText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //FadeOut();
    }

    public void FadeOut()
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("FadeOut");
    }

    public void FadeIn()
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("FadeIn");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to implement the delay for your script to run with. Here is an example for your Start method that will make it so.

Inside your FadeInOutSaveGameText class

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f); // wait one second
    // Some start logic if needed
}
```